# boost asio ssl - trying to send a request after connection succeeds

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I modified the client sample included with boost. Everything works as expected if I send my request in the handle_handshake method.

What I would like to do is connect to the server, after this succeeds send a request or multiple requests. If I attempt to send a request after handle_handshake I am getting an error message in the handle_write routine - uninitialized.

All calls are async so the path that works is 
call connect
handle_handshake is called
handle_handshake calls a method that writes a message to the server

The only change I am making is I do not call the "send message" routine inside of handle_handshake.

My app works very similar to the chat example (with the one execption - mine does not work)

using the code below everything works.

```
void handle_handshake(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
 if (!error)
 {
  std::stringstream request_;

  request_ << "GET /api/0/data/ticker.php HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  request_ << "Host: mtgox.com\r\n";
  request_ << "Accept-Encoding: *\r\n";
  request_ << "\r\n";
  boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(request_.str())
 ,boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error,
  boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}
else
{
  std::cout << "Handshake failed: " << error.message() << "\n";
}
}
}
```

Am I missing something? I need to be able to make multiple requests to the server after I have connected.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing something. The asyc_connect call I had io_service.run. Next I called asyc_write and followed this with io_service.run(). I needed to add io_service.reset() after the first call

Boost doc 
io_service.reset

This function must be called prior to any second or later set of invocations of the run(), run_one(), poll() or poll_one() functions when a previous invocation of these functions returned due to the io_service being stopped or running out of work. This function allows the io_service to reset any internal state, such as a "stopped" flag.